# undefined offset: 1, when trying to access a jpg file within a folder

Tags: php, html, explode

I got this error and I dont know why. I tried to change the code but nothing happened.

Its on the line:
    `if ($system[1] == $filters[$f]){$files[] = $file;}`
I tried to change the value to 0, and it show nothing.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
function directory($dir,$filters)
{
$handle=opendir($dir);
$files=array();
if ($filters == "all"){while(($file = readdir($handle))!==false){$files[] = 
$file;}}
if ($filters != "all")
{
    $filters=explode(",",$filters);
    while (($file = readdir($handle))!==false)
    {
        for ($f=0;$f<sizeof($filters);$f++):
            $system=explode(".",$file);
            if ($system[1] == $filters[$f]){$files[] = $file;}
        endfor;
    }
}
closedir($handle);
return $files;
 }
    $folder = "photobooth/photobooth/Michelle_Illona_Alexander/animated/"; //folder tempat gambar disimpan  
    $handle = opendir($folder); 
    $i = 1;
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle) )){  
    if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
$file2=str_replace("_mp4.jpg","",$file);
$file3=substr($file,0);
$filenames= directory(".","jpg");
foreach ($filenames as $value)
{
        echo '<li>'.
        '<a href="photobooth/photobooth/Michelle_Illona_Alexander/animated/'.$file2.'.mp4">
        <img src="photobooth/photobooth/Michelle_Illona_Alexander/animated/'.$file.'" width="300" title="" type="jpg"></a>'.
        '<br/></li>';  
    if(($i % 4) == 0){  
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '<br/>';
        }     
        $i++;
        if($i==0)
           break;
}
 }    
}  
?>
```

Comment: can you share the exact error showing?

Comment: its undefined offset 1 on line 54 which is : if ($system[1] == $filters[$f]){$files[] = $file;}